How can I increase the font size in the SSMS database user dialog?
In Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS), how can I increase the font size in this database user GUI?

I am using version 18.8 of SSMS.

I doubt this is configurable on its own. Probably have to set zoom level for the whole desktop.

Does this answer your question? SSMS 2017 Changing font size

As a side note, 18.8 is an "odd" version to be using. It's neither the latest release of SSMS, nor the last release of SSMS 18. The last version of SSMS 18 was SSMS 18.12.1, and the latest release is 20.1.

@Luuk  Nope, afraid not.  That answer doesn't address this part of the GUI.

@JoelCoehoorn  Windows does not seem to provide a way to increase the font size in this GUI.  I might either have to use some kind of 3rd-party accessibility tool, or take screenshots of the GUI each time I use it and blow up those screenshots.

Joel is saying to change the "zoom level" of the entire desktop environment, @arnoldbird , of course there's no settings in Windows for a specific application. Though, again, you are using an outdated version of SSMS, and there were several fixes/improvements to the zoom level on SSMS for high DPI screens since 18.8. I suggest updating your SSMS first.
